# Seleccionar uno de los Radio button por defecto cuando abro la página

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con AngularJS, y cuando abro la página tengo un formulario con dos radio button y un botón enviar. Todo me funciona correctamente pero ninguno de los dos radio button que tengo no me salen seleccionados por defecto. Estoy usando un ng-repeat para los radio button y creo que es lo que hace que se me complique saber como hacerlo.

Os dejo aqui el código HTML y el script para facilitaros mi problema.

```js
 $scope.selected = 'Crédito hipotecario';
    $scope.radioOptions = [
       { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'Crédito hipotecario' },

       { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'Crédito personal' },
    ];
```

```html
 <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label" ng-repeat="option in radioOptions">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="formulario.tipo" value="{{option.value}}" ng-required="!formulario.tipo" ng-checked="true">
                            {{option.name}}

                        </label>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Así tampoco me funciona pero gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que he hecho es crear un atributo más en radioOptions para indicar cual debe estar seleccionado al principio.

```js
     $scope.selected = 'Crédito hipotecario';
        $scope.radioOptions = [
           { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'Crédito hipotecario', checked: 'true' },
    
           { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'Crédito personal', checked: 'false' },
        ];
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" ng-repeat="option in radioOptions">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formulario.tipo" value="{{option.value}}" ng-required="!formulario.tipo" ng-checked="{{option.checked}}">
                   {{option.name}}
    </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ahora si! ya me funciona. Muchas gracias!